# React: How do I fix getting undefined when passing api data to child component using axios?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, axios, undefined

I'm having problems accessing data that I pass it to a child component.  This may have to do with the Promise not being resolved at the time of accessing it but that's what I don't know how to fix.  What I need is to make sure the data is fully retrieved from the parent and then passed to the child component ApplicationStats.

This is the code I wrote for the parent component:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import ApplicationStats from './ApplicationStats';

const Apps = () => {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState([]);
  const ifaUrl= 'url1';
  const orgUrl = 'url2';

  const fetchData = () => {
    const ifaResponse = axios.get(ifaUrl);
    const orgResponse = axios.get(orgUrl);
    axios.all([ifaReq, orgReq]).then(
      axios.spread((...responses) => {
        setApiData({
          ifaResult: responses[0];
          orgResult: responses[1];
        });
      }),
    );
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="card-deck"
      <ApplicationStats apiData={apiData} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

This is the child component:

```
import React from 'react';

const ApplicationStats = ({apiData}) => {
  const {ifaResult, orgResult} = apiData;
  console.log(ifaResult.data);

  return (
    <div>Hey</div>
  );
};
```

In the child component, if I replace `console.log(ifaResult.data)` with `console.log(ifaResult)`, I get this undefined and then I get the data.

[image: undefined]

What I'm trying to do is to keep my `console.log(ifaResult.data)` in the child component, but I get this

[image: error]

I've even tried using async/await, but I feel I'm missing something important.

Comment: where is `responses` defined?

Comment: It doesn't have to be defined, it get passed down from the `.then()` to `axios.spread(...responses)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're initializing `apiData` as an array, rather than an object. Here's the issue, demonstrated:

```js
let x = [];
const { property } = x; // property === undefined!
console.log(property.data) // ERROR! Cannot find property `data` of undefined
```

The reason this breaks is because when Javascript checks an object for a property that doesn't exist, it returns undefined. However, when you check for a property off of `undefined`, JavaScript will throw an error.

This will prevent you from getting the error, and will log `undefined` to the console instead of breaking:

```js
const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({ ifaResult: {}, orgResult: {}});
```

Another Contrived Example:

```js
const x = undefined;
x.data // ERROR!

//...

const x = {}
x.data // undefined
```

Comment: This worked! But I ran into another problem.  If I want to access the data array, I imagine I would have to do something like `ifaResult.data[0].propertyName` but that doesn't work.  Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: The data array contains 379 json objects (If I'm calling it correctly)

Comment: That's strange, it seems like that would work. Is it breaking for the same reason? Throwing some kind of error while it's undefined? If so, you'd need some form of conditional render so that you're only reading the `propertyName` if you're sure `ifaResult.data` exists

Comment: In the parent component I kept my useState as `useState({ ifaResult: [], orgResult: []})`.  I store my data as `setApiData({ ifaResult:responses[0].data })` which gives me the object array I need and pass that to the child component as `ifaData={apiData.ifaResult}` .  When I do a `console.log(ifaData)` in the child component, I get a line that displays the empty square brackets and then another line that displays the actual object array.  If I change the console log to `console.log(ifaData[0].org), it says "Cannot read property org of undefined".

Answer (score 1):

Your initial value for `apiData` is an empty array.

When the Ajax response arrives you replace it with an object that has a `ifaResult` property.

… but by then you’ve already rendered the component using the initial data and got the error.

———

When you set the initial data for the state, make it the same shape as the data you intend to put in it later.